# Excel user defined function to accept named range intsead of cell range

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

Have followed some instructions to create a user defined function to replicate the TEXTJOIN function in recent versions of Excel. It works to create a function that you can then use as any other, to output contents of a cell range to a single cell, separated by commas.

This works well however I have been unable to get this function to accept a named range instead of a cell range. Is this possible?

Syntax is as follows:
=My_Text_Join(“,”,1, name-of-namedrange)

```
Option Explicit
Function My_Text_Join(delimiter As String, ignore_empty As Boolean, text_range As Range) As String

Application.Volatile
Dim c As Range
Dim n As Long
n = 0
For Each c In text_range
 If ignore_empty = True Then
 If VBA.IsEmpty(c.Value) = False Then
 If n = 0 Then
 My_Text_Join = c.Value
 Else
 My_Text_Join = My_Text_Join & delimiter & c.Value
 End If
 n = n + 1
 End If
 
 Else
 
 If n = 0 Then
 My_Text_Join = c.Value
 Else
 My_Text_Join = My_Text_Join & delimiter & c.Value
 End If
 n = n + 1
 
 End If
Next

End Function
```

Comment: You might find MS doc. [Refer to Named Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-named-ranges) helpful.

Comment: I tried your coded with a named ranged (named `prueba`) and it worked perfectly. I've used like `=My_Text_Join(";";1;prueba)`. What error are you getting? How are you calling your named range?

Comment: Your code is fine. Are you sure your defined name is actually returning a range, and that you are passing it properly - i.e. as `name-of-range` not `"name-of-range"`

Comment: I have this working now. Unbelievably it was as simple as the quotation marks used around the delimeter. I had copied and pasted the syntax from the example I followed, and the were 66's and 99's vs straight lines!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code (can take a variable number of arguments of different types - contiguous or non-contiguous ranges, names, constants; e.g `=TXTJOIN("/",THENAME,C1:C3,"Fourth",777)`:

> **Edit:**
> Added feature - if an argument can be evaluated as Range, it will be converted to Range: if name `THENAME` was defined, `=TXTJOIN("/","THENAME",C1:C3,"Fourth",777)` and `=TXTJOIN("/",THENAME,C1:C3,"Fourth",777)` outputs the same result

```
Option Explicit

Public Function TXTJOIN(Delimiter As String, ParamArray args() As Variant)
    Dim A As Variant, cl As Range
    TXTJOIN = vbNullString
    For Each A In args
        On Error Resume Next
        Set A = Names(A).RefersToRange    ' if an argument can be evaluated as Range, it will be converted to Range
        On Error GoTo 0
        Select Case TypeName(A)
            Case "Range"
                For Each cl In A
                    TXTJOIN = IIf(TXTJOIN = vbNullString, cl.Text, _
                              TXTJOIN & Delimiter & cl.Text)
                Next
            Case Else
                TXTJOIN = IIf(TXTJOIN = vbNullString, A, _
                          TXTJOIN & Delimiter & A)
        End Select
    Next
End Function
```

> **Edit2:** refactoring has been done, added skipEmpty, fixed Names issue

```
Option Explicit

Public Function TXTJOIN(Delimiter As String, skipEmpty As Boolean, ParamArray args() As Variant) As String
    Dim A As Variant, cl As Range, buffer As String
    For Each A In args
        If TypeName(A) = "String" Then ' if an *string* argument can be evaluated as Range, it will be done
            On Error Resume Next
            Set A = Names(A).RefersToRange
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        If TypeName(A) = "Range" Then
            For Each cl In A
                buffer = cl.text    ' buffer is used to minimize the number of cell reads
                If Not skipEmpty Or Len(buffer) > 0 Then _
                   TXTJOIN = TXTJOIN & Delimiter & buffer
            Next cl
        Else
            If Not skipEmpty Or Len(A) > 0 Then _
                TXTJOIN = TXTJOIN & Delimiter & A
        End If
    Next A
    TXTJOIN = Mid(TXTJOIN, Len(Delimiter) + 1) ' remove lead Delimiter occur
End Function
```

Comment: I noticed one issue. If you use a number eg, 1, it will display the 1st named range, 2, the second etc. The order is not consistent though so I'm not sure if it's in order that the ranges were created, or...... A high number though like 777 displays as the number, as it is too high to refer to any named range. In my workbooks anyhow.

Comment: @ayecee It's because Names is Collection and items can be obtained by number or key. See Edit2 of the solution

Comment: Something in the 2nd edit stops it from working. I get a #VALUE! error. When I revert to 1st code it works again.

Comment: Сheck the arguments, the first version has 2+, the second version has 3+ (skipEmpty added)

Comment: Do you mean did I enter the args exactly as you have written? I have copied and pasted.

Comment: I did mean the args in the function call from worksheet

Comment: Oh understood now. I thought the blanks were being skipped as default. Have added the extra arg in the function call and works perfectly.